# Function inside 2nd AJAX call is happening before the 1st AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two ajax calls which run one after the other. In the second ajax call, once the response is recieved, the data is passed to another function for processing and then returned back. The data from the response of the first ajax call and the returned value from the function call in the second ajax call are then combined and passed to update a set of charts.

Here is the ajax calls code:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: {$js_url} + '/wp-content/plugins/WickCustomLD/categoryDataGrabAjax.php',
                        data: {"userID" : chosenSudent},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var response = data;
                            var response = JSON.parse(response);
                            alert(response);
                            ;
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(request.responseText);
                        }
                        });                     
                        
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: {$js_url} + '/wp-content/plugins/WickCustomLD/quizHistory.php',
                        data: {"userID" : chosenSudent},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var response2 = data;
                            var response2 = JSON.parse(response2);
                            
                            returnedData = randomQuizExtractFunc(response2);

                            updateConfigAsNewObject(chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4, chart5, randomQuizChart, response[0],
                                           response[1], response[2], response[3], response[4], response[5], response[6],
                                                      returnedData[0], returnedData[1]);    
                    
                            var result_table = makeTableHTML(response2);
                            quizHistoryDiv.innerHTML = result_table;
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#quizHistoryTable').DataTable( {
                                    
                                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                                    buttons: [
                                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                                    ]
                                    
                                });
                            });
                            ;
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(request.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

Here is the function which is called in the second ajax call and returned back:

```
function randomQuizExtractFunc(quizHistData) {
                    var randomQuizList = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<quizHistData.length; i++) { 
                        if (quizHistData[i][0].startsWith("Random") == true) {
                            randomQuizList.push(quizHistData[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    randomQuizList.sort(function(a,b){
                          return new Date(a[2]) - new Date(b[2])
                        })
                    
                    var randomQuizDataScores = [];
                    var randomQuizDataDates = [];
                    
                    for(var i=0; i<randomQuizList.length; i++) { 
                        randomQuizDataScores.push(randomQuizList[i][1]);
                        randomQuizDataDates.push(randomQuizList[i][2]);
                    }
                    
                    return [randomQuizDataScores, randomQuizDataDates];
                    
                    
                }
```

The issue I have is that despite the first ajax call having data returned (evidenced from the initial ajax call's alert script), when the program is run, I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

It would appear that the function in the second ajax call is executed before the data is returned from the first ajax call, but I don't understand why as code should surely be executed in the order in which it is written?

Any help on how I can get response data into the chart update function call (along with the returned data from the function in the second ajax call) would be greatly received.

Comment: It's executed with that order, but if you need to wait for the ajax to finish you can use promise or something like that or add the second ajax in the success

Comment: If you need the response from the first ajax call, you should make sure, you use something like ".done" in your ajax request, where you trigger the second one, to make sure, the response exists.

Comment: Thank you both. Are either able to provide example code?

Comment: @sw123456 Done. I've added some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to wait for the ajax to finish you can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/bg/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but check if your project needs to support older browser: [Promise support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises)

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: {$js_url} + '/wp-content/plugins/WickCustomLD/categoryDataGrabAjax.php',
        data: {"userID": chosenSudent},
        success: function (data) {
            var response = data;
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(response);
            resolve(response);//resolve the promise
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            reject(request.responseText);//reject the promise
        }
    });
}).then((response) => {
    //if the promise is resolved enter here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: {$js_url} + '/wp-content/plugins/WickCustomLD/quizHistory.php',
        data: {"userID": chosenSudent},
        success: function (data) {
            var response2 = data;
            var response2 = JSON.parse(response2);
            returnedData = randomQuizExtractFunc(response2);
            updateConfigAsNewObject(chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4, chart5, randomQuizChart, response[0],
                    response[1], response[2], response[3], response[4], response[5], response[6],
                    returnedData[0], returnedData[1]);
            var result_table = makeTableHTML(response2);
            quizHistoryDiv.innerHTML = result_table;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#quizHistoryTable').DataTable({

                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ]

                });
            });
            ;
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    });
}, (error) => {
    //if the promise is rejected enter here
    console.error(error); // Stacktrace
});
```

> Off topics and hints founded in your code:
>
> 1. why don't you combine both ajaxes
> 2. use  `dataType: "json"` instead
>    `var response = data;var response = JSON.parse(response);`,
> 3. what is this part with `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: Thank you for this. I really appreciate the time you have spent on it. I am sure this does the required, however, in my case, response is still not accessible in the second ajax call for some reason?

Comment: @sw123456 sorry my mistake didn't see that you are using it in the success of the second ajax just change `.then((data_from_prev_ajax) => {` to `.then((response) => {`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you ever so much! Great job!!